# Upgrading TFS 2012 (spanish) to TFS 2017 (english)

Tags: team-foundation-server

I'm planning an upgrade of my TFS 2012 tier. When I run the configuration wizard, the verification warnings me that the language between version differs.

How can a I solve this issue? Is there a way to pre convert my current TFS 2012 installation to english prior to upgrade?
What kind of problems can I have if I proceed with the upgrade anyway?

Comment: Is it a warning or an error? Warnings are there to make sure that you know, they dont block the process.

Comment: It's a warning. I'm not sure what kind of issues I will face if I proceed